OpenCV: how to force the opencv window to appear always on the back-most of all windows?
This is the code that I use for showing the videostream from webcam to opencv GUI
import cv2 
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

while(True): 
    ret, frame = vid.read() 
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break

vid.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


When you run the code, the GUI will be appear on top of other app.
But I want the GUI will always appear on the back-most of all other window app
Since I will build this app in linux ubuntu with pyinstaller. Also I will run the app simultaneously with other applications. I want when I open or start the app, the GUI of videostream wont appear in the top of other app, but in the back-most of all the apps windows. Because I didnt want to show the GUI to other, but I still need the GUI.

OpenCV is not a GUI library. you should expect to need an actual GUI library to achieve your goal. OpenCV has a window creation flag for "topmost" but not for "bottom-most".
